# Save state WebView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I'd like to have webview which saves state in Fragment. What I want. I want to save state on my webview in fragment when I switch the Fragment by Navigation Drawer. I found some code to save the state, but actually I don't know where to write it. Can someone help me with that, please? I am sorry for my English.

Here is code for savestate

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
   mWebView.saveState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
   mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

**This is my code**

```
public class Zastupovanie extends SherlockFragment{

    private Context context;
        
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle saved){

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.zastupovanie, group, false);
        final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),  "", "Prosím čakajte. Prebieha načítavanie... ", true);
    
        final WebView myWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.zastupovanie2);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        });
    
        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false); 
        myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        myWebView.getSettings()
           .setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);   
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); 
        myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);      
        myWebView
            .loadUrl("http://soszm.edupage.org/substitution/?");
    
        return v;
    }
        
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply add this Methods to your Fragment like this:

```
public class Zastupovanie extends SherlockFragment{

    Context context;
    private WebView myWebView

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        myWebView.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        myWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle saved)
        {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.zastupovanie, group, false);
        final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),  "", "Prosím čakajte. Prebieha načítavanie... ", true);

        myWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.zastupovanie2);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        });

        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false); 
        myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);   
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); 
        myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        myWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);

        myWebView.loadUrl("http://soszm.edupage.org/substitution/?");

        return v;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly :) But sometimes the app crash down, but maybe it's because of RAM or something is wrong ?

Comment: @user2900523 I have also found my app stability took a nose dive when saving and restoring webview states. Lots of crashing internally. Did you ever find a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

## Webview in BottomNavigationView

I am using web-view in one of the fragments in BottomViewNavigation. The solution provided by @Rafael T is a solid one. But `onSaveInstanceState()` is not called when you navigate to another Fragment in BottomNavigationView. So I saved and restore the state of Webview like this.

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private Bundle webviewstate;
    private Webview mywebview;

    // Saving state
    @Override
    public void onPause(){
       super.onPause();
       webviewstate = new Bundle();
       mywebview.saveState(webviewstate);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){

       if(webviewstate==null){
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://soszm.edupage.org/substitution/?");  //Load the page for first time
       }else{
            myWebView.restoreState(webviewstate);    // Restore the state
       }

    }

}
```