# Load webview data from cache set in ViewPager

Tags: android, webview, android-viewpager

I'm working on one app in which i need to set webView as an item of ViewPager. I did that using creating `newInstace()` of fragment every time as size of arrayList of URLs i have.
But, i have more than 20 URL to load, so it takes too much load if i set `mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(myArray.size())`. and if I use `mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1)`, then it reloads every time. So, is there any way to prevent reloading of webpage every time?

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends BaseFragment {

    Activity activity;
    private int media_position = 0;
    private String media_url = "";

    private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "CategoriesFragment:Content";
    private String mContent = "???";

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int media_position, String media_url) {

        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        fragment.media_position = media_position;
        fragment.media_url = media_url;
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString(KEY_CONTENT, mContent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if ((savedInstanceState != null) && savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_CONTENT)) {
            mContent = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        web1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        activity = getActivity();

        mWebView1 = (WebView) web1.findViewById(R.id.webview);

        mWebView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        mWebView1.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        mWebView1.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        mWebView1.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        mWebView1.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebView1.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mWebView1.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView1.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);

        mWebView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                boolean isLoaded = false;

                if (Utils.LoadedUrlList.containsKey(Utils.currentUrl)) {
                    Log.e("Matched key", "media_position --> " + media_position + " currentUrl --> " + Utils.currentUrl);
                    isLoaded = true;
                } else {
                    Log.e("Not Matched", "media_position --> " + media_position + " media_url --> " + media_url);
                    isLoaded = false;
                }

                Log.e("onPageStarted", "onPageStarted");

                if (!isLoaded)
                    if (media_position == 0)
                        ShowProgressDialog(activity, activity.getString(R.string.loading));
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                Log.e("onPageFinished", "onPageFinished");
                Log.e("onPageFinished", "--> " + url);

                hideProgressDialog();
                CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

                for (int i = 0; i < Utils.SocialURLList.size(); i++) {

                    if (url.equals(Utils.SocialURLList.get(i))) {
                        Utils.LoadedUrlList.put(Utils.SocialURLList.get(0), true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        mWebView1.loadUrl(media_url);
        return web1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
}
```

Once WebView loaded and onPageFinished called, you can save data into cookies. 
Also add `webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);`

Comment: How can i load webpage again from cookies?

Comment: When you call webview.load(url), it will automatically calls.

Comment: Also add webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);

Comment: And i need to put webview.load(url), in onPageSelected() ?

Comment: No. You dont need. when next time calls webview, it will check if cache available

Comment: mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1). This will load current and next fragment only

Comment: it doen't load from cache. please check edited question. i added sample of code.

Comment: LOAD_CACHE_EL‌​SE_NETWORK will take from cache when internet is not available

Comment: yes, but i also put CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync() at onPageFinished(). yet, it is not working.

Comment: You cant save the entire page to Local. For that you need to so something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/10836042/2610010.

Comment: Yes. But you have to do it from JS. Also check weather you can save the state in SavedInstanceState (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20125101/2610010)

Comment: I'll try both. Thank you for your kind response.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same thing. I found that saving the data in `onSaveInstanceState` did not scale well (I didn't try the cookie method suggested by @Ameer).

Instead, after you download the HTML, you can save the HTML to a file like this:

```
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter =
                new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput(email_id + ".txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(email_body);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
```

and also saving the `email_id` with the current time in `SharedPreferences`.

And then when the fragment loads again, check if the `email_id` exists in `SharedPreferences`. If it doesn't, or if the time saved with it is more than your desired cache length, then (re)load the page from the web. Else, call the cached `email_body` like this

```
public String getCachedHTML(String email_id) {
    String ret = "";
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput(email_id + ".txt");

        ret = readFile(ret, inputStream);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "Email cache not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "Can not read email cache: " + e.toString());
    }
    return ret;
}`
```

You can set the HTML on a webview like this:

```
webView.loadData(email_body, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: i think, it is not working in my case. because i need to load gmail, fb webPage